# >library(Rcmdr) #fails to load

Tags: r, knitr

I have tried the following steps:

> install.packages("Rcmdr", dependencies=TRUE)
>   install.packages("knitr", dependencies=TRUE)
>   library(Rcmdr)

output for this step is below

```
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcmdrMisc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘knitr’
Error: package ‘RcmdrMisc’ could not be loaded
```

I'm working in Rversion=3.4.1 & Rstudio=1.0.143

Comment: Does `install.packages("knitr")` complain about something?

Comment: >install.packages("Rcmdr", dependencies=TRUE)
>library(Rcmdr)

#the above work when I changed back to an earlier version of R (3.4.1 to 3.3.0) in which 'knitr' is not required
-I have to change back to 3.4.1 to source the output of 'knitr' (definitely not an error message), but got a fatal breakdown of R warning already in the first switch